# Google Fit Api Android getting daily steps by hour and total time of exercise

Tags: android, google-fit

I am currently working on an android project, which has to collect daily info from google fit api. I have searched a lot, but I have not found answers for 2 questions:

- How to get steps bu hours with array. For example from 1pm to 2pm I have walked 100 steps, from 2pm to 3pm 200 steps.
- How to get the total amount of time that the user exercised that day.

Thank you very much in advance)

Answer (score 1):

For your first part of point. 
If you form a data read request with proper segmented start and end time alongside bucket and aggregation functionality you can retrieve data buckets of each hour. 
Below is the code that I am using to retrieve hourly data for any given start and end date.

```
fun getReadDataRequestBuilderAggregated(startDate: Date, endDate: Date): DataReadRequest? {
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal.time = startDate.setDayStartTime()
        var startTime = cal.timeInMillis
        cal.time = endDate.setDayEndTime()
        var endTime = cal.timeInMillis
        return if (startTime>endTime) {
            null
        } else {

            return DataReadRequest.Builder()
                    .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
                    .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                    .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                    .enableServerQueries()
                    .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build()
        }
    } 

private fun Date.setDayEndTime(): Date {
        val currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            time = this@setDayEndTime
        }

        currentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23)
        currentTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59)
        currentTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59)

        return currentTime.time
    }

    private fun Date.setDayStartTime(): Date {
        val currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            time = this@setDayStartTime
        }

        currentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
        currentTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
        currentTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
        currentTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0)

        return currentTime.time
    }
```